# Upload in chunks to Google Cloud Storage error out 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: jquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload file in chunks using **jQuery** and **Google Cloud Storage v1beta2 Json API** into Google Cloud Storage. I am performing following steps as described in [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#resumable).

**First Step:** Post a request to get UploadId

> ```
> POST /upload/storage/v1beta2/b/test-bucket-01/o?uploadType=resumable&name=args-master.zip HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.googleapis.com
> Connection: keep-alive
> Content-Length: 0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://www.trial.com
> Authorization: Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_UptViwI44N8A3Pg89q3lKS7ZesTqYplm0whTdTJFOj0MHjtp-yM7dB8GzfJk62lIuo
> ```

In the response I get location header which includes UploadId

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Location: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1beta2/b/test-bucket-01/o?uploadType=resumable&name=args-master.zip&upload_id=AEnB2UoOYm9JYDAPNPisFKG5yheFdRF8oVaxpRHg62BGGBVr2Ue-sg3fbOmg1Ol-PFSXY60aPcl_hDaJP9176ZF6DPaCDAyDkg
> Vary: Origin
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.trial.com
> Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Cache-Control, Content-Length, Content-Type, Date, Expires, Location, Pragma, Server,
> ```

**Second Step:** Put request with UploadId and content

> ```
> PUT /upload/storage/v1beta2/b/test-bucket-01/o?uploadType=resumable&name=args-master.zip&upload_id=AEnB2UoOYm9JYDAPNPisFKG5yheFdRF8oVaxpRHg62BGGBVr2Ue-sg3fbOmg1Ol-PFSXY60aPcl_hDaJP9176ZF6DPaCDAyDkg HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.googleapis.com
> Connection: keep-alive
> Content-Length: 262144
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Content-Range: bytes 0-262143/1361678
> Authorization: Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_UptViwI44N8A3Pg89q3lKS7ZesTqYplm0whTdTJFOj0MHjtp-yM7dB8GzfJk62lIuo
> Origin: http://www.trial.com
> ```

In response of the PUT request I get 503 Service Unavailable error.

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.trial.com
> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
> Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Content-Length, Content-Type, Date, Server, Transfer-Encoding
> ```

I tried to upload in chunks with XML API of Google Cloud Storage also but got the same error. 
Please suggest what is going wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any errors in your requests.  While you are not specifying X-Goog-Content-Length/Type like the documentation says, it should still work.  Can you send a trace to gs-team@google.com?

Answer (score 4):

I got the solution it was my mistake. As mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#resumable), Google is very particular about chunk size.

> Chunk size restriction: All chunks must be a multiple of 256 KB (256 x
>   1024 bytes) in size, except for the final chunk that completes the
>   upload. If you use chunking, it is important to keep the chunk size as
>   large as possible to keep the upload efficient.

I was sending one byte less than the limit, that's why I was getting the error.

Still I am surprised Google was sending 503 error for my mistake rather than 4XX error which was misleading.

Hope this will help others.

Comment: The Content-Length in your request was 256 KB exactly, and Content-Range as well.  Does that mean you were sending less bytes than those headers indicated?